# caching json data in an array and referencing the ids to populate the type

Tags: php, arrays, json, session, caching

My function returns a bunch of attribute ids and it's corresponding names in json format. For eg:

```
{
    "DETAILS": [
        {
            "ATTR_ID": "522",
            "ATTRIBUTE_ID": "4222",
            "ATTRIBUTE_TYPE": "email",

        },
        {
            "ATTR_ID": "523",
            "ATTRIBUTE_ID": "4006",
            "ATTRIBUTE_TYPE": "interest",


        }
    ]
}
```

I need to store it in an array which i need to cache .( I'll be probably using $_SESSION)

Now another function returns me set of attribute ids:

```
 $val_array = $subarray[arrayOfAttributes];
    foreach ($val_array as $val)
    {
        print "Attrib Value: $val\n"; //This will print ids 4222,4223,etc
    }
what I need to do is correspond the ids with the type from the cache nad print out the respective Types.
```

I am unable to formulate this logic into code.

Comment: To just store in a $_SESSION, you could always just serialize(json_decode()) it, and then unserialize(json_encode()) it when you need it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function getAttrType($id, $array){
  // $array is your 'DETAILS' array.
  foreach($array as $a){
    if($a['ATTR_ID'] == $id){
      return $a['ATTRIBUTE_TYPE'];
    }
  }
}

print getAttrType(523, $array); // will output 'interest'
print getAttrType(522, $array); // will output 'email'
print getAttrType(123, $array); // will output nothing
```

No idea if this is what you're looking for, maybe this can get you in the right direction.